# Здравствуйте.Данны две cимволные массивы.Один из них строка, а другой слово.Не могу найти сколько есть в строке такое слово?

Tags: c++

Данны две cимволные массивы.Один из них строка, а другой слово.Не могу найти сколько есть в строке такое слово?

Например
"abdh heh urjd heh jj"-строка
"heh"-слово
Должен в ответ получить 2

Comment: Посмотрите функцию [`strstr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr).

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned wcount(const char* arr, const char* word)
{
    const char* first = strstr(arr, word);
    unsigned count = 0, ws = strlen(word);
    while (first) {
        ++count;
        // пропускаем слово, чтобы искать в остальной части
        first += ws; 
        first = strstr(first, word);
    }
    return count;
}
```